# YAVL: Yet another vectorized loop in R

Tags: r

I'm only just getting a handle on vectorizing code with R (links to useful examples would help), and I'm trying to find a faster way of handling this loop. a,b,c all have a bunch of numbers in them and I'm trying to find any particular number that occurs in all 3 columns. The loop works, but is super slow:

```
for(i in 1:length(a)){
  if(any(a[i]==b))
    if(any(a[i]==c))
      print(a[i])
}
```

Is there an apply function that would work really well here?

Comment: Obviously you would want to sue `%in%` rather than "==". With that correction, Vectorizing and apply-functions do not always improve performance. In this case they might even hurt, since there might be efficiencies to be gained if the overlaps of the '' and 'b' vectors were not so great. If no match for an item you do not need to check for c-membership.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
x <- 1:5
y <- 4:10
z <- 4:8
> Reduce(intersect,list(x,y,z))
[1] 4 5
```

Answer (score 3):

I see you have accepted @joran solution, but it is really hidden loop. This is a "vectorized" solution:

```
> x <- 1:5
> y <- 4:10
> z <- 4:8
> x[ (x %in% y) & (x %in% z) ]
[1] 4 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also count the total number of times each appeared (assuming there are no duplicates in each; if so, run `unique` on them first.  This code also returns the desired numbers as characters; it could be converted back as needed.

```
x <- 1:5; y <- 4:10; z <- 4:8
foo <- table(c(x,y,z))
names(foo)[foo==3]
## [1] "4" "5"
```

Comment: I upvoted it because it looking "elegant" but when I benchmarked it it performed very slowly in comparison with the others offered so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can also improve your `for loop` by using `intersect` within a for ( basically it what it is done within Reduce)

```
intersect.list <- function(list) {  ## code from stabperf package
  if (is.null(list)) return(NA)
  # Handle empty list
  if (length(list) < 1) return(NA)
  # Start with first element of list
  int <- list[[1]]
  for (v in list[-1]) { int <- intersect(int, v) }
  return(int)
} 

intersect.list(list(x,y,z))
4 5
```

### benchmarking :

```
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(1)
N <- 1e6
x <- sample(1:100,N,rep=T)
y <- sample(1:100,N,rep=T)
z <- sample(1:100,N,rep=T)

vectorized <- function()x[ (x %in% y) & (x %in% z) ]

 microbenchmark(intersect.list(list(x,y,z)),
+                vectorized(),
+                Reduce(intersect,list(x,y,z)),times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
                             expr      min        lq    median        uq      max neval
    intersect.list(list(x, y, z))  73.2862  75.14838  76.77792  85.54216 121.8442    10
                     vectorized() 131.9560 132.40266 134.47248 139.93902 172.7829    10
 Reduce(intersect, list(x, y, z))  88.4308  90.06320  92.72929 128.05930 133.2982    10
```

As you see the for loop if slightly faster then Reduce and vectorized solution.

Comment: Also, similar to yours and joran's `ff <- function(list, int = list[[1]]) { if(is.null(list) || !length(list)) return(NA); if(length(list) == 1) return(int); Recall(list[-1], intersect(int, list[-1][[1]])) }
`; `ff(list(x, y, z))`